# How to find app_secret for whatsapp business api

Tags: node.js, whatsapp-cloud-api

I was doing coding in node js but in that it there is requirement of setup like that

```js
APP_ID=<<YOUR-WHATSAPP-BUSINESS-APP_ID>>
APP_SECRET=<<YOUR-WHATSAPP-BUSINESS-APP_SECRET>>
RECIPIENT_WAID=<<YOUR-RECIPIENT-TEST-PHONE-NUMBER>>
VERSION=v13.0
PHONE_NUMBER_ID=<<YOUR-WHATSAPP-BUSINESS-PHONE-NUMBER-ID>>
ACCESS_TOKEN=<<YOUR-SYSTEM-USER-ACCESS-TOKEN>>
```

I got all credential accept `app_secret`. I am unable to find that if anyone know how can I get `app_secret` please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

I searched on dashboard but couldn't find that.

Comment: You need to generate an access token, refer to [this doc](https://medium.com/@turivishal/permanent-access-token-for-whatsapp-business-apis-c81e1dfc86c7)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Go to App Settings, and click on 'Basic.' Then, click on 'App Secret' and select 'Show Secret:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your app-secret is part of your app dashboard on developers.facebook.com.

1. Once you open 'https://developers.facebook.com/' click on log-in on the top right, then 'My Apps'.
2. Select your app form the list.
3. Click on App Settings - Basic on the left menu.
4. Your app secret will appear.